# ProcessStartInfo and JLine

Tags: vb.net, processstartinfo, jline

Using ProcessStartInfo in Visual Basic, I want to redirect a Java application I/O handled by the JLine library.
Output is ok, **input doesn't work**.

I found [Process.StandardInput.WriteLine Not working on Java.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14509439/3453226).
OP solves the issue by **stopping JLine**.

**Is this a safe solution?**
Do you know other ways to solve this?

Comment: Include the code you're actually using here in the question.

Comment: @AndrewMedico I lost it because I asked this question months ago. However, I am still interested in an answer.